# How to get today's date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, time

I would like to a way to get the current date in Javascript.

I would also like the date to be displayed in this format:
`dd month year @ hh:mm:ss EDT`

for today's date that would work out to:
`04 Aug 2011 @ 20:24:38 EDT`

Thanks

Comment: The title made me think you were looking for a script to commemorate today's Juno launch.

Comment: Why all those downvote to a new user? I think he deserve some comments and advices on why the question is not right.

Comment: People freak out when they see words like "Hey" or "Yo".  Avoid those in your question.  Personally, it doesn't matter to me, and I did NOT downvote, but others are clearly bothered by this.  I've edited the wording of the question.

Comment: yeah whats up with the downvotes???....Im not even a hardcore Javascript programmer..I just needed the direction where to go..I could have used google, but I like it here...Im noticing alot of people think they are better than other people in here

Comment: @WEFX: Why do you assume that's the reason for the down-votes? If you hover the down arrow, the first reason it gives is *"This question does not show any research effort;"*. I didn't down-vote, but if I was to guess, I'd say that's the reason why, and I'd say it's legitimate.

Comment: @Jose Faeti: New user? This user has asked 20 questions.

Comment: @user748656: You should show what you've attempted so far in finding a resolution to your issue.

Comment: Ok maybe he asked already 20 questions, but to me, a downwote ALWAYS need to carry an explanatory comment with it, at least the first one who downwoted should specify the reason, all the others may follow.

Comment: @patrick dw, you make a good point.  I shouldn't assume that every single downvote was caused by the slang terms.  However, I know any time I see a question w/ slang terms, it ALWAYS has a few downvotes.  With the new, edited title, I assume most people will either A) answer the question, or B) scroll right on past (and not downvote).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var d=new Date();
d.toUTCString();
```

Is this what you need?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily build it yourself with the [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)'s various properties. To get a Date object representing the current moment in time, use

```
var now = new Date();
```

Comment: thank for that link man...now I see all the different properties...cool

Answer (score 1):

Go grab [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). It can do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
new Date();
```

will give you the current date.

Answer (score 0):

```
let currentDate = (date = new Date()) => `${date.getDate()}/${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getFullYear()}`

console.log(currentDate());
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.